# Merge two LinkedHashMap in Scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, merge, linkedhashmap

Having this code

```
def mergeWith[K, X, Y, Z](xs: mutable.LinkedHashMap[K, X], ys: mutable.LinkedHashMap[K, Y])(f: (X, Y) => Z): mutable.LinkedHashMap[K, Z] =
  xs.flatMap {
    case (k, x) => ys.get(k).map(k -> f(x, _))
  }
```

it gives me this:

```
val map1 = LinkedHashMap(4 -> (4), 7 -> (4,7))
val map2 = LinkedHashMap(3 -> (3), 6 -> (3,6), 7 -> (3,7))

val merged = mergeWith(map1,map2){ (x, y) => (x, y) }
merged: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap[Int,(Any, Any)] = Map(7 -> ((4,7),(3,7)))
```

But what i want is this:

```
merged: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap[Int,(Any, Any)] = Map(3 -> (3), 4 -> (4), 6 -> (3,6), 7 -> ((4,7),(3,7)))
```

How to modify my code to obtain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done with the current `mergeWith()` signature. In particular, you're trying to create a `LinkedHashMap[K,Z]` but there is no `Z` input. The only way to get a `Z` is to invoke `f()` which requires both `X` and `Y` as passed parameters.

So if `xs` is type `LinkedHashMap[Int,Char]` and has element `(2 -> 'w')`, and `ys` is type `LinkedHashMap[Int,Long]` and has element `(8 -> 4L)`, how are you going to invoke `f(c:Char, l:Long)` so that you have a `[K,Z]` entry for both keys `2` and `8`? Not possible.

If the `mergeWith()` signature can be simplified you might do something like this.

```
def mergeWith[K,V](xs: collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap[K, V]
                  ,ys: collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap[K, V]
                  )(f: (V, V) => V): collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap[K,V] = {
  val ns = collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap[K,V]()
  (xs.keySet ++ ys.keySet).foreach{ k =>
    if (!xs.isDefinedAt(k)) ns.update(k, ys(k))
    else if (!ys.isDefinedAt(k)) ns.update(k, xs(k))
    else ns.update(k, f(xs(k), ys(k)))
  }
  ns
}
```

This produces the desired result for the example you've given, but it has a number of undesirable qualities, not the least of which is the mutable data structures.

BTW, there is no such thing as a `Tuple1` so `(4)` is the same thing as `4`. And whenever you see type `Any`, it's a pretty good sign that your design needs a re-think.